# How to select particular value from dropdown using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to programming and trying to automate a scenario using selenium webdriver. I have this scenario where I need this below code and I want to select a t-shirt size from the dropdown which is available in stock. Can someone please guide me how can I do this?

I tried the options with selectwithIndex, selectwithvisisbletext etc. But in this case I first need to check which size is available and then select that one from the dropdown.

```html
<div class="dbk-select dbk-select_full">
<select class="dbk-form--input">`enter code here`
  <option value="true" disabled="" style="display: none;">Select Size</option>
  <option value="false" data-value="479804001088140">140</option>
  <option value="false" data-value="479804001088152">152</option>
  <option value="false" data-value="479804001088164">164</option>
  <option value="false" data-value="479804001088176">176 (out of stock)</Option>
</select>
```

Comment: The code you are talking of is the 'data-value' attribute on the option tag? I am assuming you have the value of this code and trying to choose that option if it is available.

Comment: What do you mean need to check which size is available?? do you want to select any option from dropdown except `(out of stock)`??

Comment: Yes I want to select an option from the dropdown except "Out of stock"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select an option from the drop down based on availability then you can try the below code snippet

```
/**
 * Call this method with expected size to select and with the drop down
 * element By locator
 *
 * @param expectedSize     the size which needs to select from drop down
 * @param by               By locator to find select web element
 * @return                 if the expected option selected then returns true
 */
public static boolean selectByText(String expectedSize, By by) {
       boolean isExpectedSizeSelected = false;
       WebElement dropdownElement = driver.findElement(by);
       Select dropdown = new Select(dropdownElement);
       List dropdownOptions = dropdown.getOptions();
       for(WebElement option : dropdownOptions) {
             // Condition to validate option element is not null 
             if(option != null) {
               String actualSize = option.getText();
               if(actualSize == expectedSize) && !expectedSize.contains("out of stock")) {
                   dropdown.selectByVisibleText(actualText);
                   isExpectedSizeSelected = true;
               }
             }
       }
       return isExpectedSizeSelected;
}
```